# Google map InfoBubble ERROR in infobubble.JS

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-street-view

I am trying to create an infoBubble in Google panoramic/Street view. It is looking good and feeling good. But I have an error on my browser console like

```
var mapDiv = map.getDiv();
   ***uncaught typeerror: undefined is not a function(REPEATED 16 TIMES)***
var gutter = arrowSize * 2;
var mapWidth = mapDiv.offsetWidth - gutter;
var mapHeight = mapDiv.offsetHeight - gutter - this.getAnchorHeight_();
var tabHeight = 0;
var width = /** @type {number} */ (this.get('minWidth') || 0);
var height = /** @type {number} */ (this.get('minHeight') || 0);
....
....
....
```

And this is my info bubble code:

```
infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
      minHeight: 350,
      shadowStyle: 0,
      padding: 0,
      borderRadius: 13,
      arrowSize: 0,
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
      disableAutoPan: true,
      hideCloseButton: true,
      arrowPosition: 50,
      arrowStyle: 2
    });
```

My guess is, we have to add the mapDiv with our infoBubble code. But I don't know how it is!

Comment: Are you using API v2 or API v3? Please correct your tags accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your kind reply... I am using api3      '<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false"></script>'